# SMTPServerDisconnected issue

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp

My Google app engine application needs to send out email(what ever we get the data from screen). On development server i specify my smtp configuration (host,port,user,password) while starting the server. then I am running my application in that form after I  submitted the data its showing error as

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 500, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\desk\Desktop\apps\temp\main.py", line 139, in post
    """)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 205, in send_mail
    message.send(make_sync_call)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail.py", line 474, in send
    make_sync_call('mail', self._API_CALL, message, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 68, in MakeSyncCall
    apiproxy.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 240, in MakeSyncCall
    stub.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 80, in MakeSyncCall
    method(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 203, in _Send
    self._SendSMTP(mime_message, smtp_lib)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 139, in _SendSMTP
    smtp.quit()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 730, in quit
    res = self.docmd("quit")
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 362, in docmd
    self.putcmd(cmd,args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 318, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\smtplib.py", line 310, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first**
```

its telling that SMTPServerDisconnected, please run connect() first
following code I am using

mail.send_mail(sender="abc@xyz.com",
              to="def@xyz.com",
              subject="Test Message",
              body="""
              Dear Albert:

```
          Your example.com account has been approved.  You can now visit
          http://www.example.com/ and sign in using your Google Account to
          access new features.

          Please let us know if you have any questions.

          The example.com Team
          """)
```

please tell me what is the wrong in this code i am new to Python and Google Apps

I am waiting for any one reply
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Which SMTP server are you configured to use?: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_Mail

SMTP Host is going to be the SMTP server's (i.e. your mail relay) fully qualified domain name (not an email address, but a server name on the network).

Comment: I am taken sample code of same what it mentioned here (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_Mail)
specifically I am not configured any SMTP server in my local, its taking the path from Python..

Comment: Er, using 'smtp.example.com' as in that example is obviously not going to work. What's your exact command line?

Comment: HiJohnson... for smtp_host mail id I given my email id, not given 'smtp.example.com' this is what my command line 
dev_appserver.py --smtp_host=xyz@abc.com --smtp_port=25 --smtp_user=aaaa --smtp_password=bbbb temp

where temp is my application

tell me from where I can get host,port, username,password  details?

Comment: --smtp_host needs to be the hostname of a mail server to send email to, not an email address.